# React.js insert script tag from remote CDN

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to insert scripts into the header of my page (or at least they have to be loaded before the `render` method of my component is called).

The scripts in question are from [here](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/docs/#api_methods) if it matters :

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<!-- Firebase -->
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.2/firebase.js'></script>

<!-- Firechat -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firechat/2.0.1/firechat.min.css' />
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firechat/2.0.1/firechat.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @jurgemaister How can I make sure those are inserted/loaded into the global scope before the render method (or willMount) of my component is called. I cannot put it for every page in my app, just when the component is called.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I would rather comment this but I do not possess 50+ reputation.

---

You can place your scripts in your `index.html` file before you load your react bundle.

Comment: You are doing the right thing posting this as answer. Comments are for asking additional information.